# MS Remote Desktop to Windows - Not enough space in a shared folder

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, copy-paste

Not quite sure if it's a right place to ask but I'll try. I use MS Remote Desktop to connect from iMac to my remote Windows 10 computer and exchange files between two computers through a Redirected Folder (the folder itself is on my iMac, and it's visible in Windows as a network drive among other drives like C:).

The issue is when I am trying to paste some files into the Redirected Folder through Windows File Explorer, it returns an error: 
[image: screenshot from windows machine]
Since my remote desktop is in Russian here is the translation:

> **1 action aborted**
>   No enough space at \\tsclient\MyRedirectedFolderName. In order to copy these files the destination should have extra 439 Kb

The requested space is always different depends on files I paste.

Meanwhile, I still can save files into the folder from any other apps (e.g. I just saved a large PDF file opened in Adobe Acrobat through *Save as*). Additionally, I don't have this issue when I connect through my MacBook.

Any chance to fix it?

Comment: So it only happens when you **paste** a file? I noticed a space in the folder name, though those are allowed in Windows they are a delimiter in macOS. What if you share a folder with no space in the name. Perhaps you found a file copy edge case, or perhaps my brain turned to mush on vacation...

Comment: Steve, yes it only happens when I paste a file (or several) into the folder. The folder name doesn't matter (I was trying to paste into another folder named Downloads but it didn't help either, still the same error).

Comment: Wierd, sorry, those were by best guesses...

Comment: I already had this issue a year ago (I was trying to copy very large files then and it failed), but the issue disappeared once I re-installed MacOS. Unfortunately, this time  re-installation didn't help :-( (And no, I didn't re-install just because of the problem, just wanted to have a clear installation of Catalina).

Comment: There was some issue in the Microsoft Remote Desktop app. I had a three weeks long conversation with Microsoft support, and as a solution they released a beta version of the app (version 10.3.4 - 1688) which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac beta version 10.3.4 (1688) solves the issue.